# Wordpress cron job running more than once

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-cron, cron

I developed a plugin to read some XML files and publish their itens as post but for some reason, sometimes, it is duplicating posts. Basically that is what I have:

```
// function one is scheduled (hourly) and unscheduled on plugin activation and deactivation hooks
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'function_one_activation');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'function_one_deactivate');

function function_one_activation() {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('function_one_cron')) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'function_one_cron');
    }
}

function function_one_deactivate() {
    $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled('function_one_cron');
    wp_unschedule_event($timestamp, 'function_one_cron');
}

add_action('function_one_cron', 'one');
add_action('function_two_cron', 'two');
add_action('function_three_cron', 'three');

function one() {
    // download XML files using CURL and save on server
    // schedule cron to run function two after 60 seconds
    if(!wp_next_scheduled('function_two_cron')) {
        wp_schedule_single_event(time() + 60, 'function_two_cron');
    }
}

function two() {
    // get an array from DB of posts saved from XML files
    // get and run each file and check if item is new (is not on array above) and save it as post, if already posted remove it ID from array
    // save the "new" array
    // schedule cron to run function three after 60 seconds
    if(!wp_next_scheduled('function_three_cron')) {
        wp_schedule_single_event(time() + 60, 'function_three_cron');
    }
}

function three() {
    // get the remain ID from array above and delete posts
}
```

Does anyone know what I am missing that makes it runs twice sometimes or how can I prevent it to happens?

Comment: note that your functions refer to accessing arrays from other functions, but that's not how requests in PHP work. When a request has been handled, everything is wiped clean, and the next request loads WP again from a blank slate. Variables do not persist, and there is no constant application process like a Node or Java web application. It's also unclear why you're scheduling single cron jobs from a plugin activation hook, this is highly unusual. Are you using a load balancer or multiple servers?

Comment: Hey thank you for replying... I hidden some part of code just to ilustrate the step by step process, even the functions name I changed here and I didn't mentioned this array is saved as an option_value using wp_options table to persist the data... the plugin is working fine, but sometimes it causing the wp-cron.php to process more than once

Comment: Are you using a load balancer or multiple servers/computers to serve your site? Have you checked with a plugin such as WP Crontrol or the WP CLI cron commands for duplicates scheduled entries? It's critically important that you answer the load balancing/multiple servers question as quickly as possible.

Comment: As far as I know I am not using load balancer but I don't know much about hardware. WP Control only shows one cron for the first function since the other two are being scheduled as a single event and not hourly as the first one I think what might be happen is that the whole process is taking too long to finish and the second function is still running after one hour and function one starts running again, how can check if a single cron event is still running?

Comment: I would strongly advise against having cron jobs triggering other cron jobs, it's much more efficient and reliable to have a regular cron job that checks for tasks in a queue to do, rather than individual cron jobs that are chained together. If you had a load balancer or multiple servers then there would be a trivial fix of only running WP Cron on a single server

Comment: Tom, thank you for the advise. I am now just calling function two directly inside function one (instead of schedule it) and it seems to be working better now. Also, I've increased cron to run every 3 hours because one of the XMLs takes more than one hour to finish (read and save as post) it has only one huge update daily and I think it was somehow  duplicating wp_schedule_single_event(). I am going to check a little more time and come back soon

Comment: most servers will stop your request running after a minute, 1 hour is way too long, this cron job is only feasible from a CLI command

Comment: I noticed if something is schedule to run hourly it runs for one hour (that is why I increased for every 3 hour) and then suddenly stops (not sure if it crashes or if WordPress  has a way to "treats" it to run the next schedule, but it doesn't stop after 1 minute only)... about the xml reader, it was running ok for two days but today at midnight it duplicated posts again... I am starting to believe there is something else causing this since I have other plugins (newsletter, shares post to FB) which also uses cron and sometimes same thing happens, not sure how to debug it

Comment: A WP Cron job that runs for an hour or longer is an alarming thing to have that needs addressing/refactoring urgently, it's very likely that you're getting duplicates because you have multiple attempts happening at the same time and overlapping.